# determine the range of p to have distinct real roots for the following equation; $x^2+(p-q)x+(1-p-q)=0$

Tags: quadratics

$\forall q$ determine the range of p to have distinct real roots for the following equation;
$$x^2+(p-q)x+(1-p-q)=0$$

**My Try**

$\Delta\geq0$

$(p-q)^2-4(1-p-q)\geq0$

I know I have to isolate p in this inequality to get a range for p in terms of q.

$p^2+p(4-2q)+q^2+4q-4\geq0$

How should I proceed? Please help! Thanks

Comment: So this expression's $\Delta_q<0$ since q^2 coefficient is positive so I'm getting 1<p is this correct?

Comment: $\Delta >0$ not equal. Else is correct.

Comment: Noted. Since roots are distinct I see..